# The rules for scoring when interacting with a CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, excel, csv, google-sheets, row

import csv

def check_day(date_to_check):
file_path = "data.csv"
try:
with open(file_path, mode='r', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
reader = csv.reader(file)
next(reader)  # Skip the header
for row in reader:
if row[0].strip() == str(date_to_check):
print(f"The date you are checking is {date_to_check}.")
return True
print(f"The date {date_to_check} does not exist in the CSV file.")
return False
except Exception as e:
print("An error occurred while reading the CSV file:", e)
return False

def range_day(date_to_check):
file_path = "data.csv"
start_index, end_index = None, None
try:
with open(file_path, mode='r', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
reader = csv.reader(file)
next(reader)  # Skip the header
for index, row in enumerate(reader):
if row[0].strip() == str(date_to_check):
start_index = index
elif start_index is not None and row[0].strip() != "" and row[0].strip() != str(date_to_check):
end_index = index - 1
break
if end_index is None:
end_index = index  # If no new date is found, it will end at the last line
if start_index is not None and end_index is not None:
# Skip row index 0
start_index += 1
end_index += 1

```
        return start_index, end_index
    else:
        print(f"The date {date_to_check} was not found in the CSV file.")
        return None, None
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred while reading the CSV file:", e)
    return None, None
```

def count_task_values(input_date):
start_index, end_index = range_day(input_date)
if start_index is None or end_index is None:
print("Unable to count tasks as the date was not found in the CSV file.")
return None

```
task_values = []  # List to store task values corresponding to that date

try:
    file_path = "data.csv"
    with open(file_path, mode='r', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)  # Skip the header
        for index, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
            if index < start_index or index > end_index:
                continue
            if row[1].strip() and row[2].strip():
                task_values.append((row[1], row[2]))  # Save the task value to the list
            elif not row[1].strip() and row[2].strip() and task_values:
                # Combine into one task if row[1] is empty, row[2] has a value, and at least one task has been stored
                last_task = task_values[-1]
                task_values[-1] = (last_task[0], last_task[1] + ', ' + row[2])  # Combine the value of the old task and the new task

    if task_values:
        print(f"On {input_date}, there are {len(task_values)} tasks:")
        for task_value in task_values:
            print(f"Task 1 -- CAM : {task_value[0]} --  MC  : {task_value[1]}")
    else:
        print(f"There are no tasks on {input_date}.")
    return task_values
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred while reading the CSV file:", e)
    return None
```

## Call the function and check the date value in the CSV file

input_date = int(input("Enter the Date to Check: "))
if check_day(input_date):
range_day(input_date)
count_task_values(input_date)

Comment: please format your code so as to easily understand

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). There is no question presented in your post. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)